# WPF Can't change time in DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I'm trying to change Date in the second calendar every time when i change date in first. Problem is, date in second calendar doesn't update days. For example: when i pick 10th of january 2018 on first calendar i should have as first possible day to select 11th of january 2018 on second calendar, and i can select all days except for first. Here's my code:

```
private void DateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Date2.DisplayDate = Date1.DisplayDate.AddDays(1);
        Date2.DisplayDateStart = Date1.DisplayDate.AddDays(1);
        Date2.DisplayDateEnd = Date1.DisplayDate.AddDays(93);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that at the time the event is fired off, the Date1.DisplayDate has not yet updated. You can confirm this in the debugger. Try Date1.SelectedDate instead.

```
private void DateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Date2.DisplayDate = Date1.SelectedDate is null ? null : ((DateTime)Date1.SelectedDate).AddDays(1) as DateTime?;
    Date2.DisplayDateStart = Date1.SelectedDate is null ? null : ((DateTime)Date1.SelectedDate).AddDays(1) as DateTime?;
    Date2.DisplayDateEnd = Date1.SelectedDate is null ? null : ((DateTime)Date1.SelectedDate).AddDays(93) as DateTime?;
}
```

Note that you may want to change the Date2.SelectedDate as well.

Update: Looks like the SelectedDate is a nullable DateTime. I added a check to see if it is null. If it is a non-null DateTime, I convert it to DateTime to access the AddDays() extension method and then cast it back to nullable DateTime.

Comment: Date1.SelectedDate don't have AddDays method :/

Comment: Hero <3 ("Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.") 
Can't upvote ;__;

Comment: (had to change Date2.DisplayDate to Date2.SelectedDate in first line for it to work)